# How Can I make This Algorithm Generic?

Tags: java

I am working on an object cache of CMS objects.  I need to maintain a parent/child relationship between a Product and child objects (Options and Attributes).  The parent (Product) is illustrated in the first code sample.

It is easy enough to do, but I am looking for a way to make the assignment of the child to the parent, as shown in the 2nd code block, generic.

Since all CMS objects extend CMSContent, I can use ProductID.  However, is there a way to make the field (e.g. ProductAttribute) generic so that I can put the algorithm in a method and call the method with a parent and child object to make the attribute assignment?

I know that an ORM framework like Hibernate is appropriate here, but that won't fit since I have a fixed database structure.

```
public class Product extends CMSContent {
    private List<ProductAttribute> productAttributes;
    private List<ProductOptions> productOptions;

    // getters,setters
}
```

Algorithm to match them up.

```
// attach Product Attributes to Product
for (Product p : listP) {
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for (ProductAttribute po : listPA) {
        parameters.put("pid", p.getPid());
        parameters.put("ref", po.getRid());

        int i = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sqlAttr, parameters);  // select count(*), 1 if matched.

        if (i == 1) {
            p.getProductAttributes().add(po);  // generic field?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you envision the generic method signature looking like? It's not clear what the generic parts of this algorithm are, it seems like you'd always be associating a `List<ProductAttribute>` with a `Product`

Comment: But I need to associate a ProductOption with a Product in the same manner.  But I would have to change p.getProductAttributes().add(po) to p.getProductOption().add(po);.  Until I can do that, i can't make it generic

Comment: I don't think generics are the tool to solve this with then

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this two Methods in Product help

```
public void add(ProductAttribute item){
  productAttributes.add(item);
}
public void add(ProductOption item){
  productOption.add(item);
}
```

so you should be able to just add a ProductAttribute or a ProductOption

Comment: That looks very promising, but the problem I am running into now is that "add" is not defined in the supertype (CMSContent)